# Unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy, redis, python-unicode

Now I use elixir with my mysql database and the redispy with redis and i select UTF-8 at all the place.
I wanna to get some data writing in chinese like `{'Info':‘8折’，'Name'：'家乐福'}` but what i got is like this:

```
{'Info': u'8\u6298', 'Name': u'\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f'}
```

and after i store this dict to redis and get it out by redispy it becomes:

```
{"Info": "8\u6298", "Name": "\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f"}
```

I know if i add `u'` before `8\u6298` and print it it will shou me `"8折"` but is there a function or another solution to this problem?

Comment: How sure are you that the second is actually a `dict`?

Comment: i split all the value and send them to the redis as a list. when i want to got the value i just pull them out and make it as a dict in the program

Comment: So if you print out the actual value you get `8\u6298` then?

Comment: yes. So i need a way to convert those 8\u6298 back to '8 折'. In the shell i can easily add a u' by hand but in code i cann't

Comment: I would really like to know why redis gets it wrong in the first place, rather than how to fix it.

Comment: I test it in the shell : >>> a=redis.Redis()>>> b=u'\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f'>>>a.set('3',b)>>>print a.get('3')>>>家乐福 its right

Comment: It seems you stored the string incorrectly in the first place. Can we see the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter looks like json, try decoding it first:

```
import json

resp = '{"Info": "8\u6298", "Name": "\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f"}'
print json.loads(resp)

## {u'Info': u'8\u6298', u'Name': u'\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just seeing the `repr` (representational) string. But it's the same unicode in the internal string.

Try this:

```
Python2> d = {'Info': u'8\u6298', 'Name': u'\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f'}
Python2> d
{'Info': u'8\u6298', 'Name': u'\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f'}
Python2> print d["Name"]
家乐福
```

Oh, but you are not getting that back. You have the non-unicode form back. One quick hack is to eval it.

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(d["Name"])
```

But better would be to figure out why the system is not round-tripping the unicode.

Comment: Except the repr doesn't have the `u` prefix.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It does in Python 2.x.

Comment: if there is no u' print It would be 8\u6298 but not '8折' it is my question

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OIC, it's coming back out as repr text. I guess it should be encoded before storing.

Comment: the eval still goes wrong,look here:>>>a='\u5bb6\u4e50\u798f' >>>ast.literal_eval(a) >>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    \u5bb6\u4e50\u798f
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 1):

You add u' before 8\u6298, python store this value as an unicode instance, which has no encode format.

Before you put the data into redis, you have to encode your unicode instance, make it to be a real string.

You select UTF-8 at all the place, so just

```
>>> x=u'8\u6298'
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> y=x.encode('utf8')
>>> type(y)
<type 'str'>
>>> y
'8\xe6\x8a\x98'
>>> print y
8折
```

Store y instead of x. The you read from database, the output will be a string `'8\xe6\x8a\x98'` (8折), not a python instance `'8\u6298'` any more.

Comment: That's the python interface  redis-py's duty to do that. Encode before ouput/input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the unicoded version of the string, take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode)