# How to print national characters in list representation?

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing JSON data with special characters (å, ä, ö) to file and then reading it back in. Then I use this data in a subprocess command. When using the read data I cannot make special characters get translated back to å, ä and ö respectively.

When running the python script below, the list "command" is printed as:

```
['cmd.exe', '-Name=M\xc3\xb6tley', '-Bike=H\xc3\xa4rley', '-Chef=B\xc3\xb6rk']
```

But I want it to be printed like this:

```
['cmd.exe', '-Name=Mötley', '-Bike=Härley', '-Chef=Börk']
```

Python Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, json, codecs, subprocess, sys


def loadJson(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as input:
        data = json.load(input)
    print 'Read json from: ' + filename
    return data

def writeJson(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        json.dump(data, output, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    print 'Wrote json to: ' + filename



# Write JSON file
filename = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'test.json' )
data = { "Name" : "Mötley", "Bike" : "Härley", "Chef" : "Börk" }
writeJson(filename, data)


# Load JSON data
loadedData = loadJson(filename)


# Build command
command = [ 'cmd.exe' ]

# Append arguments to command
arguments = []
arguments.append('-Name=' + loadedData['Name'] )
arguments.append('-Bike=' + loadedData['Bike'] )
arguments.append('-Chef=' + loadedData['Chef'] )
for arg in arguments:
    command.append(arg.encode('utf-8'))

# Print command (my problem; these do not contain the special characters)
print command

# Execute command
p = subprocess.Popen( command , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Read stdout and print each new line
sys.stdout.flush()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

Comment: print the strings in the list instead of the list and the special characters will magically reappear

Comment: `M\xc3\xb6tley` _is_ `Mötley`, encoded in utf8, just as you wrote. Your code is fine.

Comment: @hop - Printing the list like that was just to illustrate that the values did not contain the åöä characters. It's in the subprocess.Popen where I get the real problems, as the arguments are not containing the åöä characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867749/unicode-in-python)

Comment: @fredrik: a) you are wrong. b) your problem is probably windows. c) are you sure cmd.exe can handle utf-8?

Comment: @hop - you were right. I was wrong. The code is correct. Cmd.exe was just some executable I picked to illustrate my imaginary issue. Thank you.

Comment: The strings _are_ utf-8 -- it just that `print command` is outputting the `repr()` of each member of the list. Try `for s in command:`, `print s` and it should look OK.

Comment: You can pretty print it with `print '[' + ', '.join("'"+elem+"'" for elem in command) + ']'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the canonical representation of string constants in Python which is designed to eliminate encoding issues. Actually, it's what `repr()` on a string returns. List's `str()` function implementation that is called when it's printed calls `repr()` on its members to represent them.

The only way to output a string with non-ASCII characters as they are is to `print` it or otherwise write it to a stream. See [Why does Python print unicode characters when the default encoding is ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii#answer-2597260) on how character conversion is done on printing. Also note that for non-ASCII 8-bit characters, the output will be different for terminals set up for different codepages.

Regarding the solution:

The simplest one will be to make an alternative `str(list)` implementation that will call `str()` instead of `repr()` - noting the warnings above.

```
def list_nativechars(l):
  assert isinstance(l,list)
  return "[" + ", ".join('"'+str(i)+'"' for i in l) + "]"
```

Now (in `cp866` console encoding):

```
>>> l=["йцукен"]
>>> print list_nativechars(l)
["йцукен"]
```

With data in foreign encoding:

```
# encoding: cp858
<...>
l= ['cmd.exe', '-Name=Mötley', '-Bike=Härley', '-Chef=Börk']
print list_nativechars(l)

c:\>python t.py
["cmd.exe", "-Name=MФtley", "-Bike=HДrley", "-Chef=BФrk"]
```