# Want Python 27 to print out foreign characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, jinja2

I am working on a school project using Google App Engine and Python 2.7. I am trying to output a nested dictionary like so: `{city:[{song1:artist1},{song2:artist2}], city2:[{song1:artist1},{song2:artist2}]}`. However, the city names and the songs are from around the world, with special foreign characters. When I print out the dictionary, I get this string:

`{'uOsaka'[{'u\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d': u'Takajin Yashiki}`, etc... (where Osaka is the city, the unicode is the song, and Takajin is the artist)

Does anyone know how to get the name of the cities/songs to appear correctly?

Comment: Printing it out should work fine. Also, what terminal are you on?

Comment: I am using this dictionary to pass to a Jinja template where it will be outputted in a html file. Printing individual values would work fine yes, but I am concerned with how they appear in the dictionary because that's ultimately what I will be passing. And I am using powershell on Windows.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the output you get?  You seem to be missing a `:`, and `'u\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d'` is far more likely to be `u'\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d'`

Comment: I assumed that was just a typo, but worth confirming.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for the typos! I was missing a colon after Osaka, and I did mean u'.

Comment: Just tested Unicode characters with Jinja, works like expected.

Comment: If I pass my dictionary into Jinja, with this code in the html template:<h1>Hello</h1>
{{citiesAndSongs}}    then, when running google app engine it opens localhost and outputs the dictionary. However, some city names aren't displayed properly. u'Bras\xedlia' and u'Bogot\xe1' are a couple examples of special character cities that don't output as they should.

Comment: Change to Python 3 and all these problems will quietly disappear..

Comment: I actually wrote it in python 3 originally, and it works perfectly. Google app engine doesn't work with python 3 however.

Comment: @KatherineWaller ugh, I feel for you. For all the complaining people did, Python 2 - > 3 was worth it for the unicode changes alone. Anyway, you should add your situation with Jinja /Google App engine, I'm going to go ahead and tag those as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and reading JSON with Python, how to decode/encode special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138046/writing-and-reading-json-with-python-how-to-decode-encode-special-characters)

Comment: Google App Engine does actually work with [Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/), right now it's in Beta but you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue in python 2.7 is that printing a dictionary involves converting it to a string, and that string will be a `str` rather than a `unicode`. Hence your output.

However when your render the **individual** items you will find they are fine:

```
>>> d = {u'Osaka': [{u'\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d': u'Takajin Yashiki'}]} 
>>> for k, v in d.viewitems():
...   for pair in v:
...     for song, artist in pair.viewitems():
...         print k, song, artist
... 
Osaka ゆめいらんかね Takajin Yashiki
```

Note that this is a Python 2 behavior. In Python 3, where `str` is text, this data will be printed as UTF-8 and should render naturally in the console assuming you have the necessary fonts installed for Japanese glyphs:

```
(3.7) >>> print(d)
{'Osaka': [{'ゆめいらんかね': 'Takajin Yashiki'}]}
```

Comment: Apparently, OP is encountering a problem with Jinja/ Google app engine, though. wouldn't surprise me if there was a call to `__repr__` somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Like in [How to print national characters in list representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138046/how-to-print-national-characters-in-list-representation) , you need to use a custom procedure to print your data that would print strings themselves instead of their `repr`:

```
def nrepr(data):
    city_items=[]
    for city, jukebox in data.iteritems():
       jukebox_items=[]
       for song,artist in jukebox.iteritems():
           jukebox_items.append(u'"%s":"%s"' % (song,artist) )
       city_items.append(u'"%s":{%s}' % (city, u",".join(jukebox_items)))
    return u'{%s}' % u",".join(city_items)

>>>  data={u'Osaka':{u'\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d':u'Takajin Yashiki'}}

>>> print nrepr(data)
{"Osaka":{"ゆめいらんかね":"Takajin Yashiki"}}
```

<sub>(use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the start of the file to avoid putting `u` before every literal)</sub>

You are not constrained to mimicking Python's default output format, you can print them any way you like.

---

Alternatively, you can use a `unicode` subclass for your strings that would have `repr` with national characters:

```
class nu(unicode):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.encode('utf-8')    #must return str

>>> data={nu(u'Osaka'):{nu(u'\u3086\u3081\u3044\u3089\u3093\u304b\u306d'):nu(u'Takajin Yashiki')}}
>>> data
{Osaka: {ゆめいらんかね: Takajin Yashiki}}
```

**This is problematic 'cuz `repr` output is presumed to only contain ASCII characters and various code relies on this. [You are extremily likely to get `UnicodeError`s in random places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941052/which-encoding-is-used-for-strings-in-python-2-x).** It will also print mojibake [if a specific output channel's encoding is different from `utf-8` or if further transcoding is involved.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941052/which-encoding-is-used-for-strings-in-python-2-x)